# Ruby on Rails RSpec Routing fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes

Rails newb here.

Trying to RSpec test a 200 status code for an index route.

In my **index_controller_spec.rb**:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe IndexController do

    it "should return a 200 status code" do
    get root_path
    response.status.should be(200)
  end

end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Tat::Application.routes.draw do

    root to: "index#page"

end
```

**index_controller:**

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController

    def page
    end

end
```

When I visit on my browser all is fine but RSpec command line gives **an error**:

```
IndexController should return a 200 status code
     Failure/Error: get '/'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"index", :action=>"/"}
     # ./spec/controllers/index_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

'

I don't understand?!

Thanks.

Comment: what do you get when you do `rake routes -T` ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here.  What does `rake routes` show for `root`?  Also, are you running any sort of preloader, like Spork/Zeus/Spring/etc.?  Some preloading optimizers won't automatically reload routes when they change.

Comment: yeah I'm using Spork, restarting the server doesn't change anything though. rake routes gives:

root  / index#page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the Rails world!  Testing comes in many different flavors.  It appears that you're confusing a controller test with a routing test.

You're seeing this error because `root_path` is returning `/`.  The `get :action` within an RSpec controller test is meant to call that method on that controller.

If you notice your error message, it says `:action => '/'`

To test your controller, change your test to:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe IndexController do
  it "should return a 200 status code" do
    get :page
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end
```

If you're interested in a routing test, see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs  An example would be:

```
{ :get => "/" }.
  should route_to(
    :controller => "index",
    :action => "page"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was going mental. Rails is so different from anything else I've used before!

Comment: We have all been there. The learning-curve is logarithmic... it gets much easier, but it's a continual climb.  Stick with it!